# How to make text different size from the parent div?

Tags: html, css

I want to make two lines of text with two different styles. Parent div has a size and color defined, and a child div text should be different size and color

This is my HTML code:

```
<div id=testPanel class="module toggle-wrap">
    <div id="testPanel_heading" class="mod-header">
        <ul class="ops"></ul>
        <h2 class="toggle-title">test new design</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="mod-content">Hello world!</div>
</div>
```

In my CSS file I've defined different styles for both `#testPanel` and `#testPanel_heading`:

```
#testPanel-heading{
    font-size: 14px !important;
    color: black !important
}
#testPanel{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: aquamarine   
}
```

Now `!important` statement seems to override the color style but not the font size as it renders in 20px

Please keep in mind that I cannot change the HMTL in any way whatsoever as it renders automatically. The only way for me to make changes is to inject as CSS file. Also I cannot define a style for `.mod-content` or `.toggle-title` as it will affect other blocks on the page.
Thanks

Comment: Because its `h2`, has default styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to address the heading, you need to be more specific with `#testPanel_heading > h2`, and you don't need `!important`

```css
#testPanel_heading > h2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: black;
}

#testPanel {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: aquamarine
}
```

```html
<div id=testPanel class="module toggle-wrap">
  <div id="testPanel_heading" class="mod-header">
    <ul class="ops"></ul>
    <h2 class="toggle-title">test new design</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="mod-content">Hello world!</div>
</div>
```

Also, you wrote `#testPanel-heading`, but in the HTML it is `id="testPanel_heading"` (underscore).